# Create a link for next page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm using the Twilio API in a rails app to show a user a list of their recordings.  Say a user has 11 recordings total, and I'm showing them 3 per page.

twilio_controller.rb

```
def calls

@user = current_user
@account_sid = @user.twilio_account_sid
@auth_token = @user.twilio_auth_token
@page_size = 3
@page = params[:page_id] || 0
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account
@recordings = @subaccount.recordings
@recordingslist = @recordings.list({:page_size => @page_size, :page => @page})

end
```

calls.html.erb

```
<% @recordingslist.each do |recording| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= recording.sid %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Next Page", twilio_calls_path(@page + 1) %>
```

routes.rb

```
#twilio routes

 post 'twilio/callhandler'

 get 'twilio/calls'

 match 'twilio/calls' => 'twilio#page', :as => :twilio_page # Allow `recordings/page` to return the first page of results
 match 'twilio/calls/:page_id' => 'twilio#page', :as => :twilio_page
```

Paging info is built into the Twilio response such that

```
@recordingslist.next_page
```

gives me the next 3 recordings (verified in rails console).  How do I link to that so that when a user clicks the link, the table loads the next 3 results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend utilizing the paging functionality that ships with twilio-ruby. According to [the docs](http://twilio-ruby.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/basics.html?highlight=page):

> ListResource.list() accepts paging arguments.

Start by create a route for your Twilio list view. Make sure you can pass a `page_id` parameter – this is how your controller action will know which page to render:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'recordings/page/:page_id' => 'twilio#page', :as => :twilio_page
match 'recordings/page' => 'twilio#page', :as => :twilio_page # Allow `recordings/page` to return the first page of results
```

Then, in the `page` action, pull the `page_id` parameter (or set if to `1` if there is no `page_id`, and pass the `page_number` and `page_size` as arguments to `@recordings.list`:

```
# app/controllers/twilio_controller.rb
def page
    page_size = 3
    @page = params[:page_id] || 1
    @sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
    @subaccount = @sub_account_client.account
    @recordings = @subaccount.recordings
    @recordingslist = @recordings.list({:page_size => page_size, :page => page)})
end
```

Finally, in your view, pass the page number to `twilio_page_path` in your `link_helper` – just make sure to adjust the page number accordingly (`+1` for the next page, `-1` for the previous page:

```
# view
<%= link_to "Next Page", twilio_page_path(@page.to_i + 1) %>
<%= link_to "Previous Page", twilio_page_path(@page.to_i - 1) %>
```

Note that – if you're at the start or end of your list – you may inadvertently end up passing an invalid `page_id`. Therefore, you may want to implement some exception handling in your `page` controller action:

```
# app/controllers/twilio_controller.rb
def page
    begin
        @page = params[:page_id] || 1 # If `page_id` is valid
    rescue Exception => e
        @page = 1 # If `page_id` is invalid
    end
    # Remaining logic...
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!  I'm with you on most of your suggestions but had a bit of trouble implementing your routes section.  I'll have to read up a bit more on that.  I've edited my post to include your code and page one is loading perfectly with your suggestions.  However, when I click 'next page' I am landing on twilil/calls.1 with the same data.  Would you mind taking a look?  Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Try reordering the route declarations... I've updated my code to reflect. Lemme know if that fixes things.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the lack of a 'page' action on my part?  I essentially put your page action code within my 'calls' action because that action has the view associated with it.  I then replaced 'recordings' from your routes, with 'calls' from mine.  These recordings are being shown on the call page

Comment: If you want to abstract this logic into the `call` action, you'll need to name your routes accordingly. Just substitute `page` with call in the two route declarations.

Comment: when I click 'next page' it is loading twilio/calls.1 but the new calls aren't loading.  I have `<%= debug(params) %>` in place in dev and I see instead of 'page_id' being set, it says 'format': 1.  Clicking 'next page' again will not add +1 to it.  My two route declarations say: `match 'twilio/calls/:page_id' => 'twilio#calls', :as => :twilio_page` and  `match 'twilio/calls' => 'twilio#calls', :as => :twilio_page`

Comment: Got it!  Your order of route declarations was right the first time, that gave me the :page_id in params.  Then, I needed to add `to_i` method `<%= link_to "Next Page", twilio_page_path(@page.to_i + 1) %>` to solve a "Can't convert fixnum to string error".  Thank you for all your help...I'm embarrassed to admit how much time I spent on this...

Comment: Good observation... I've amended my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gem like Kaminari for Pagination.

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: You must be joking. Kaminari as absolutely nothing to do with pagination in Twilio... even if it did, it's pretty massive overkill when you can write a rudimentary paging action, don't you think?