# Prevent datepicker values from being stripped from params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm using the bootstrap-datepicker.js (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to set the date range for a table in a rails view.

calls.html.erb

```
  <form class="form-horizontal daterange">
  <input type="text" data-date-format="yyyymmdd" id="start-date" name="start">
  <span class="add-on">-</span>
  <input type="text" data-date-format="yyyymmdd" id="end-date" name="end">
  <button type="submit" class="btn submit-date">Submit</button>
  </form>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#start-date').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      });
      $('#end-date').datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      });
      });
  </script>
```

It passes params[:start] and params[:end] into the URL that I use to set the date range for Twilio API calls.

Ex. /twilio/calls/?start=2013-03-01&end=2014-01-06

Ever since I created the following routes to paginate the api calls:

routes.rb

```
 match 'twilio/calls' => 'twilio#calls', :as => :twilio_page
 match 'twilio/calls/:page_id' => 'twilio#calls', :as => :twilio_page
```

Whenever I advance to the next page of results, it strips out the date range values.

How do I preserve the :start/:end parameters?

twilio_controller.rb **Update - added start/end data**

```
if params[:start].nil?
@start_date = DateTime.parse((Date.today - 7).to_s).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
@end_date = DateTime.parse((Date.today - 1).to_s).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
else
@start_date = params[:start]
@end_date = params[:end]
end

@user = current_user
@account_sid = @user.twilio_account_sid
@auth_token = @user.twilio_auth_token
@page_size = 5
@page = params[:page_id] || 0
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account
@recordings = @subaccount.recordings
@recordingslist = @recordings.list({:page_size => @page_size, :page => @page, :"date_created<" => @end_date, :"date_created>" => @start_date})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the canonical [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string):

> The params will also include any parameters from the query string.

Therefore, you want to eliminate the first route, which doesn't allow for any parameters:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'twilio/calls/:page_id' => 'twilio#calls', :as => :twilio_page
```

To illustrate, suppose you are trying to access `/twilio/calls/1?start=2013-03-01&end=2014-01-06`. The query string is actually parsed, such that you have access to not only the `page_id` parameter, but also `start` and `end`.

If you want to maintain a default route, e.g., `twilio/calls`, you can declare a [route redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) as follows:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/twilio/calls', to: redirect('/twilio/calls/1')
```

This will automatically reroute all requests for `/twilio/calls` to `/twilio/calls/1`.

**UPDATE**:

To clarify, URL query parameters are parameterized and fed to the corresponding controller action as members of the `params` hash. Therefore, given the path `/twilio/calls/1?start=2013-03-01&end=2014-01-06`, you'll have access to `params[:page_id]`, `params[:start]`, and `params[:end]`. You'll need to pass the latter two to your API call in your action:

```
@recordingslist = @recordings.list({:page_size => @page_size, 
                                    :page => @page, 
                                    :"date_created<" => params[:start], 
                                    :"date_created>" => params[:end]
                                  })
```

**UPDATE**:

In order to persist the query parameters across page views, you can concatenate the argument passed to `twilio_page_path` with the query string:

```
twilio_page_path((@page.to_i + 1).to_s + "?start=" + params[:start] + "&end=" + params[:end]) %>
```

Comment: This is actually a follow up question to what you helped me with earlier - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958777/create-a-link-for-next-page-in-rails.  I tried removing that route but the pagination you helped me create then fails.  Should I be trying to store those values temporarily?  I've seen a few solutions on here utilizing hidden fields.

Comment: Hi, yes – I remember this question. You shouldn't need to utilize hidden fields... in fact, it's good practice to leave pagination to the URL router. What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: No error - page loads on `twilio/calls`, set date range in date picker and page reloads to something like `/twilio/calls/?start=2013-03-01&end=2014-01-06`, I use those values as start/end dates for api calls but when I click to the next page, the params are stripped and I have `/twilio/calls/1`.  It blows out the date range so the user can never get to the next page of results in that given range.

Comment: I've updated my questions to address the context depicted in your comment.

Comment: I actually did have those values stored in variables, I just foolishly left that out of the question.  I've updated it, is it the same as what you are suggesting with your update?

Comment: More or less. What's the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: the :start and :end params were being lost when I clicked over to 'next page'.  I ended up having to do this: `twilio_page_path(@page.to_i + 1, params.slice(:start, :end))` to preserve the params from page to page

Comment: Ahh, yes. I understand what you're talking about now. You can concatenate the entire querystring with the `page_id` to preserve the querystring in your request. I've updated my answer to reflect... does this make things work?